# How to print php code in HTML tags?

Tags: php, html, echo

Hello i'm having this variable which is string.

> $this->product_output_html = <<< HTML
>
> Some HTML Code
>
> HTML;

I want int he class test to add a php for loop like this one

> if ($admin->errors) {   foreach ($admin->errors as $error) {
>        echo ''.$error.'';    } }

i have tried to add  but is not working. i added '' after the class="test"> and before the  of the test but still is not working. what i'm doing wrong?

thanks a lot

Comment: Code does not work within strings, including heredoc sections. If you meant something else, please show a complete example of what you were attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like

```
$this->product_output_html = 'Start of html code as a string';
if ($admin->errors) {
  foreach ($admin->errors as $error) {
    $this->product_output_html .= '<br />'.$error;
  }
}
$this->product_output_html .= '<br />End of html code as a string';
echo $this->product_output_html;
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
echo ".$error.";
```

with

```
echo $error;
```